# TemplateDoesNotExist at / base/index.html when deploying to heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I've been working on this issue for days and I would really love some real help here! :)

I'm brand new to Python, Django, and stackoverflow, so please let me know if more information or a different format would be helpful.

I'm trying to deploy my app on Heroku. It runs locally, but when I try to

> heroku open

I get the following error:

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /
>   base/index.html

I've seen this happen to others, and I've tried the following fixes which haven't worked:

- Changing the folder structure by putting index.html directly into templates instead of templates>base>index.html
  ([TemplateDoesNotExist when base template is in root folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30415562/templatedoesnotexist-when-base-template-is-in-root-folder?rq=1)) - This causes the app to stop running locally

  - Adding templates as an installed app (like I did for core) by adding

> (r'', include('templates.urls')),

to my urls.py

and added

> 'templates'

to my settings.py. This caused the app to stop running locally, so I changed it back.

- changed my views.py from:

> ```
> from django.shortcuts import render from django.views.generic.base
> import TemplateView
> # Create your views here. class LandingView(TemplateView):
>    template_name = "base/index.html"
> ```

to

> ```
> from django.shortcuts import render
> from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
> # Create your views here.
> class LandingView(TemplateView):  
>     template_name = [os.path.join(MAIN_DIR, 'coffeedapp2/templates')],
> ```

- checked to make sure I have standard Django 1.8x template settings ([TemplateDoesNotExist at / base/index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018847/templatedoesnotexist-at-base-index-html))

  - tried changing my views.py from:

> ```
> from django.shortcuts import render
> from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
> # Create your views here.
> class LandingView(TemplateView):
>   template_name = "base/index.html"
> ```

to

> ```
> from django.shortcuts import render
> from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
> # Create your views here.
> class LandingView(TemplateView):
>   template_name = "base/index.html"
> ```

([TemplateDoesNotExist at / at templates/index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36981074/templatedoesnotexist-at-at-templates-index-html))

I'm thinking that I may need to define a SITE_ROOT or something but whenever I try to do that it stops running locally.

**ERROR:**

> TemplateDoesNotExist at / base/index.html Request Method: GET Request
>   URL:  https://salty-journey-18003.herokuapp.com/ Django Version:  1.9.7
>   Exception Type:   TemplateDoesNotExist Exception Value:    base/index.html
>   Exception
>   Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py
>   in select_template, line 74 Python
>   Executable:   /app/.heroku/python/bin/python Python Version:  2.7.12
>   Python Path:   ['/app',  '/app/.heroku/python/bin', 
>   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-23.1.0-py2.7.egg',
>   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg',
>   '/app',  '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python27.zip', 
>   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7', 
>   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', 
>   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
>   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
>   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
>   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages'] Server time:   Mon, 1
>   Aug 2016 20:50:53 +0000 Template-loader postmortem
>
> Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
>
> Using engine django: django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
>   /coffeedapp2/templates/base/index.html (Source does not exist)
>   django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
>   /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/base/index.html
>   (Source does not exist)
>   django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
>   /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/base/index.html
>   (Source does not exist)

settings.py

"""

```
Django settings for coffeedapp2 project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MAIN_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))



# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '^h)ohz4qbhu&5po084_ob8qy+1c*h^tb#jtab!p965^8@&64q!'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'coffeedapp2.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(MAIN_DIR, 'coffeedapp2/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'coffeedapp2.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Update database configuration with $DATABASE_URL.
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Allow all host headers
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(MAIN_DIR, 'coffeedapp2', 'static'),
    )
```

coffeedapp>urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.conf.urls import patterns

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'', include('core.urls')),
)
```

core>urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
import core.views as coreviews
from django.conf.urls import include

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$', coreviews.LandingView.as_view()),
 )
```

core>views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
# Create your views here.
class LandingView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "base/index.html"
```

[See image of file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45NUY.png)

```
Relevant file structure:

coffeedapp2
  coffeedapp2
    _init_.py
    settings.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
  core
    migrations
    _init_.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    urls.py
    views.py
  static
  templates
    base
        index.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `TEMPLATES` setting, try changing your `DIRS` setting to:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

This is the usual approach, I cannot see any reason to use `MAIN_DIR` as you currently do.

Keep the template as

```
template_name = "base/index.html"
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That worked! It's coming through without the CSS on Heroku, but I can probably figure out how to fix that. Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because I was using camelcase in my HTML template name but calling it with small cases. Changed template name to small case and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. The problem was I had:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

in my settings.py instead of:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Templates')],
```

The templates directory had a capital T, but I typed it with a lowercase t in settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

makes sure your template directory is named 'templates' not 'Templates'

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with space at end of file names - e.g. in a template

```
{% include 'myapp/components/breadcrumb.html ' %}
                               # SPACE HERE ^
```

Works just fine when developing on Windows <sigh>, fails on Linux.